# Вывод результата хранимой процедуры

Tags: sql

Есть процедура с вложенной в нее процедурой:

```
`CREATE PROC Процедура_d

@FIO VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT

AS


DECLARE @AVG_price INT


EXEC Вложенная_процедура_в_d @AVG_price OUTPUT


BEGIN


set @FIO = (SELECT DISTINCT Клиент.ФИО


FROM Клиент JOIN Договор ON Клиент.ID_Клиента = Договор.ID_Клиента


WHERE Договор.Сумма > @AVG_price)


END`
```

Результатом данной процедуры должен быть столбец ФИО. В результате же выводит только одну строчку данного столбца.
Как исправить?

Comment: Отформатируйте код (кнопка `{}` над полем ввода текста). Укажите конкретный диалект.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо потому что результатом данной процедуры является строчная переменная `@FIO VARCHAR(150) OUTPUT`, а не таблица, как Вы хотите.

Comment: Знаю, что переменная не может содержать более одного значения. Значит убрать Выходной параметр из процедуры и использовать его только при вызове процедуры?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в качестве выходного параметра указать табличную переменную